# Using SQL to show conference system usage volume through the day

Tags: sql, sql-server, load, tableau-api

**Goal:** create a report that will provide the avg number of lines on our conferencing system at any time of the day based of historical data

**Given:** Conference Unique ID, Conference Start Time(Time), Conference End Time(Time), Conference Duration (basically an int of end time- start time), # of lines on each Conference. These are columns in a SQL table of ~250,000 rows representing 2 years of data.

**Problem:** This appears very easy at first. Simply run a query that finds sum of lines and group by hour and minute like below:

```
Select Datepart(hour,[Actual Conference Begin Time]) as 'Hour',
       Datepart(minute,[Actual Conference Begin Time]) as 'Minute', 
       SUM([Actual Total Lines]) as 'Lines'
From Filtered
Group By DatePart(hour,[Actual Conference Begin Time]),
         Datepart(minute,[Actual Conference Begin Time])
Order By DatePart(hour,[Actual Conference Begin Time]),
         Datepart(minute,[Actual Conference Begin Time])
```

**HOWEVER** this query only accounts for sum of lines on calls that "Start at that time". It does not capture the fact that at any given minute in the day there are multiple calls going on that all started at different times and are running for different durations.

**Proposed Solution:** My initial plan to solve this was to create another table and use a loop to fill it with a shell of every hour and minute within that hour in the day. Then essentially "parse" through my main table of data row by row and find the start time, duration, and # of lines then go to my hour/minute table and populate it starting with the begin time and down the rows for the same number of rows as the duration. It would populate each of these with "# of lines" in another column by adding to the value currently in the cell- not replacing. the hour/minute table would be in essence a big tally board of the lines on the system at any given hour/minute.

**Proposed Solution 2:** I have also thought of another potential solution. Look at each row in the database and create more rows that are identical for each minute in between the start and end time stamps. So for example, if you have a 10 minute phone call, 9 more rows would be created with all of the same info in each column, except the timestamp would be a minute greater in each row. Now there would be sufficient data in the table to run the aggregate query above.

I have created the shell table of hour/minutes, but am reaching a point where I think the above solution may not be possible in SQL. I have also attempted to manipulate the data in Tableau without result.

Please let me know if you are aware of a solution to present this information whether in SQL or by another approach. I have more code to share to show progress.

Thank you.

Comment: Use a tally table n= int from 0 to number of minutes in your period. Add n minutes to the start date of your period. That is your calendar. Now you can outer join events that cross each minute in your calendar. Add the rows after grouping by minute.

Answer (score 0):

I can't stand your column names, because the require escaping, so I'm simplifying them.

Here is the idea.  Create a new record for each start and end.  Then at each point in time, add up the number of starts versus ends and you get the number at any point in time:

```
with be as (
      select thetime, sum(inc) as in
      from (select begintime as thetime, 1 as inc
            from filtered
            union all
            select endtime,  -1 as inc
            from filtered
           ) be
     )
select thetime, sum(inc) over (order by thetime) as numConcurrentLines
from be;
```

This shows a value for each time a conference call begins and ends.  That should point you in the right direction for what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I took a look at that and another solution I found and ended up doing something like this (super simple, but not obvious on my own):

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t1 time(0)= '00:00:00'
DECLARE @t2 time(0)= '00:01:00'
DECLARE @counter int=1

While @counter<=1440
Begin
SELECT @t1 as 'Time (24hr)', SUM([Actual Total Lines]) as 'Total Lines' 
FROM Filtered 
WHERE @t2 >= [Actual Conference Begin Time] AND [Actual Conference End Time]>= @t1
Set @t1= Dateadd(minute,1,@t1)
Set @t2= Dateadd(minute,1,@t2)
Set @counter= @counter+1
End;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I took a look at that and another solution I found and ended up doing something like this- super simple, but not obvious on my own